# akka cluster- aeron not deleting temporary files

Tags: akka, aeron

I'm working on akka cluster. Every time when akka creates an Actor system instance, it is creating huge aeron-{user}-clustersystem files under temporary directory, which consumes a lot of space.

What are the akka aeron settings to be used for auto cleanup?

Please help.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: No. As a workaround, Im manually cleaning them during server startup phase.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Artiery Remoting with Aeron. Akka by defualt uses an embedded Aeron Media Driver for each instance i.e. a Media Driver is started in the same JVM as your actor system instance - this is what is causing the directory to be created.

You can use the Java system property -Daeron.dir.delete.on.shutdown=true to get the Aeron media driver to delete the directory on shutdown. It can also be configured to delete on start with -Daeron.dir.delete.on.start=true

You can limit the directory to one per host by using a single media driver per host started in its own JVM and share that with all your Actor system instances see. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting-artery.html